# How to Trigger Validation

Tags: javascript, html

How do I force a user to enter a valid time and valid number before pressing the button "Show"?

I have two fields in my html code and I found two good validation scripts in JS. One for time and one to determine if input field has a numeric value.

I can't change anything in the HTML.

```js
function checkTime() {
  re = /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/;
  if (time_untilopt.value != '' && !time_untilopt.value.match(re)) {
    alert("Wrong time!");
    return false;
  }
}

function checkRoomNr() {
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (roomopt.value.match(numbers)) {
    console.log("is number");
  } else {
    console.log("not a number!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="time-until">Time</label>
  <input type="text" id="time-until">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="room">Room</label>
  <input type="text" id="room">
</div>
<button id="show-schedule">Show</button>
```

Comment: Set up the two fields to have `input` event handlers that correspond to each of the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the validation to take place as data is being entered into the fields, you should set your functions up to run on the `input` event of the fields. If you want to wait until the user leaves the field and has made changes to the value of the field, then you can use the `change` event of the fields.

But, you'll also want the data to be checked when the form that contains the fields is submitted, so you need to set up a `submit` event handler for the form as well.

The way to connect a function to an event is to register the function as an "event handler" and that is done (using modern standards-based code) with the **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** method:

```js
// First, get references to the elements you'll want to work with.
// And, use those variable names to reference the elements in your 
// code, not their IDs.
var timeUntil = document.getElementById("time-until");
var room = document.getElementById("room");
var form = document.querySelector("form");

// We'll set up a variable to keep track of whether there are any errors
// and we'll assume that there are not any initially
var valid = true; 

// Set up the event handling functions:
timeUntil.addEventListener("change", checkTime);
room.addEventListener("change", checkRoomNr);
form.addEventListener("submit", validate);

function checkTime(evt){
  re = /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/;
  if(timeUntil.value != '' && !timeUntil.value.match(re)) {
    console.log("Wrong time!");
    valid = false; // Indicate an error
  } else {
    valid = true;
  }
}

function checkRoomNr(evt){
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if(!room.value.match(numbers)){
    console.log ("not a number!");
    valid = false; // Indicate an error    
  } else {
    valid = true;
  }
}

// This function is called when the form is submitted
function validate(evt){
  // Invoke the validation functions in case the fields have not been checked yet
  checkTime();
  checkRoomNr();
  if(!valid){
     evt.preventDefault(); // Cancel the form's submission
     console.log("Submission cancelled due to invalid data");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="time-until">Time</label>      
    <input type="text" id="time-until">
  </div>  
  <div>
    <label for="room">Room</label>      
    <input type="text" id="room">
  <div>
  <button id="show-schedule">Show</button>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkTime( val ) {                     //Pass a value
  return /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/.test( val ); //Return a boolean
}

function checkNum( val ) {    //Pass a value
  return /^\d+$/.test( val ); //Return a boolean
}

const time = document.getElementById("time-until"),
      room = document.getElementById("room"),
      show = document.getElementById("show-schedule");

function validateForm () {
  show.disabled = (checkTime( time.value ) && checkNum( room.value )) === false;
}

[time, room].forEach( el => el.addEventListener("input", validateForm) );
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="time-until">Time</label>
  <input type="text" id="time-until">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="room">Room</label>
  <input type="text" id="room">
</div>

<!-- MAKE BUTTON DISABLED -->
<button id="show-schedule" disabled>Show</button>
```

Now you can reuse your functions like `checkTime( val )` regardless of the input ID.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a starting point basically you need to add event handlers and wire up `time_untilopt`and `time_untilopt` and add `disabled` to the show button. and listen for changes. There many ways, this is just an idea.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('show-schedule');
const time_untilopt = document.getElementById('time-until');
const roomopt = document.getElementById('room');

function checkTime() {
  re = /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/;
  if (time_untilopt.value != '' && !time_untilopt.value.match(re)) {
    alert("Wrong time!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function checkRoomNr() {
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (roomopt.value.match(numbers)) {
    console.log("is number");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("not a number!");
    return false;
  }
}

function change() {
  button.disabled = !(checkTime() && checkRoomNr());
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="time-until">Time</label>
  <input type="text" id="time-until" onchange="change()">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="room">Room</label>
  <input type="text" id="room" onchange="change()">
</div>
<button id="show-schedule" disabled="true">Show</button>
```

Comment: You edited your question. Don't have time to edit my answer, but idea is same. just set up eventhandlers from code.

Comment: Inline HTML event attributes should not be used. As such. `return true/false` shouldn't be used either.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I understand the inline HTML attribute part, but what is wrong with functions returning true/false?

Comment: Returning `true` or `false` only have an impact on event handlers when you are using inline event attributes. They won't cancel the event when you wire up event handlers using `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh. I'm not preventing the event, just disabling the "show" button.

Comment: But that is not the correct way to prevent someone from submitting a form, since forms can also be submitted by pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key in many situations.

Answer (score -2):

Inside both of your functions you'll want to set up your variables (`time_untilopt` and `roomopt`) to actually point to your two `<input>` fields. Then you'll simply want to `return true` if they pass validation, and `return false` if they don't.

To trigger these checks, you'll want to set up an `onlick` attribute for your submission, which is tied in to a third function, which I have named `show()`. This third function should conditionally check that **both** of the other functions return `true`. If they do, all is good, and you can continue with the submission. If they're not good, simply `return false` in this function as well.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function checkTime() {
  re = /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/;
  var time_untilopt = document.getElementById('time-until');
  if (time_untilopt.value != '' && !time_untilopt.value.match(re)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Wrong time!");
    return false;
  }
}

function checkRoomNr() {
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var roomopt = document.getElementById('room');
  if (roomopt.value.match(numbers)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("The room number is not a number!");
    return false;
  }
}

function show() {
  if (checkTime() && checkRoomNr()) {
    console.log('Both validations passed!');
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="time-until">Time</label>
  <input type="text" id="time-until">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="room">Room</label>
  <input type="text" id="room">
</div>
<button id="show-schedule" onclick="show()">Show</button>
```

Also note that your `checkTime()` function is actually doing the exact **opposite** of what you want; if the time is not empty and matches the validation, you want to return **`true`**, not **`false`**. This has been corrected in the above example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Inline HTML event attributes should not be used. As such. `return true/false` shouldn't be used either.

Comment: I've admittedly *never* heard anyone say that those should not be used before, but looking in to it, I can see a disadvantage or two. I will look further in to Unobtrusive JavaScript :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that technique is so ubiquitous that it will probably never go away, but it hasn't been the way to set up events since DOM Level 2 came out many, many years ago. See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**.